# Mesh Collider allowing game object to climb over in Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I created a simple maze with trees, and they all have convex mesh colliders, the player(red ball) can some how climb over the trees. 
[image]
This is how the mesh looks for all the trees yet
[image]
this is happening, the ball is climbing up the trees, How is this happening?

Comment: change the convex colliders to box.. so that the trees have 90 degree borders as otherwise you can roll up a hill..

Comment: It works, but due to the size difference of each trees, the box colliders vary in size, that sometimes the player while moving does not even come close to the trees and hits one of the colliders, is there a more uniform way? cause then I would have to edit each of the colliders

Comment: you could block out with just colliders the areas with trees,  so rather than 1 per tee, take the kinda lines and follow them and smooth it out a bit

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand, what do you mean by that?

Comment: You could also measure the collision normal hit angle, and halt the ball velocity when it touches those. Or you could try increasing gravity in the global physics properties. Or maybe try giving the steep trees a physics material and setting friction to something very high.

Comment: take a bunch of trees, and put 1 big box collider on the bunch

Comment: @PhilippLenssen changing the gravity in the global physics properties worked, but I just wanna ask, does that mean for the entirety for this project the gravity is that high, or is it just applied for this scene only? and does it affect anything else?

Comment: It changes everything, which you may want or not. I've heard it being said that generally a higher gravity value creates more appropriate CharacterControllers, but I don't know if this is true or applicable for your project. The other methods I mentioned may be more appropriate and pinpointed.